Encryption support message Azure SQL Server DB
I am working with a new client, and I have to connect to their Azure SQL Server database.
I use the SQL Server connector in Power BI, I enter the server name (the one I use to connect using SSMS), then I authenticate using Microsoft account login.
I get this error:

Encryption Support
The server name provided doesn't match the server name on the SQL server SSL certificate. Please contact your administrator or see the link below for more information. Alternatively, you could change your connection encryption settings. Would you like to continue using an unencrypted connection?

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this and get on with my work. I tried using ChatGPT, internet search, but nothing useful.
A colleague of mine is using remote desktop connection, he rebooted his machine, and was able to solve this (he had the same error). I am using AWS.
Any help will be appreciated!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Strange, are you really connecting to Azure? As in the cloud, or some sort of managed instance? They should not mess up the certificates

It happened to me, ware using an OLE DB as a connector and we are connecting as SQL user with the TrustServerCertificate as true
with basic authentication because the Azure SQL database is created in a VNet.
I tried to parametrize my connection in Power Query as below to make the trust server certificate=True :
= OleDb.DataSource("provider=SQLNCLI11.1;initial catalog="&Database&";data source=
"&Server&";trust server certificate=True", [Query=qry])

